# Mongoid generic embedded_in fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a `Translation` class embedded in a `Product` class.

```
class Translation
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :key, type: String
   field :value, type: String, default: ''
   field :locale, type: String

   embedded_in :product
end

class Product
   embeds_many :translations
end
```

It work but now, I need `Translation` to be embedded in other classes :

```
class Order
   embeds_many :translations
end
```

but `Translation` still `embeds_many :translations`. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Just add `embedded_in :order` to the Translation class and it will work perfectly.

Comment: So for each class that embed `Translation` I need to add the corresponding `embedded_in` in the `Translation` class ? It will do the work but I hope there is a "cleaner" way to do that, without modifying the `Translation` class every time.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the Translation class you can move the embedded_in code to a mixin and include the mixin in the Translation class. I don't think there is a cleaner way to do it with in mongoid.